# Automatically configure PHP_INI_SYSTEM directives

Tags: php, jit, opcache

I need my project to use the following configuration directives:

```ini
opcache.enable=1
opcache.jit_buffer_size=50M
opcache.jit=tracing
```

These are **PHP_INI_SYSTEM** directives
Each time a user installs my project, they have to manually add the above directives to their php.ini or httpd.conf file

I want these directives to be added automatically for a more user friendly experience
Is there a workaround or "dirty" hack?

Answer (score 0):

you can add in htaccess

php_flag opcache.enable 0